# Accessing string in database without adding escape characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following:

```
create_table "events", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "meta_data"
end
```

When I open up Valentina Studio and look at the events table I can see one record:

```
ID           meta_data      
1         {"action"=>"bla"}
```

When I call `Event.last.meta_data` I receive the following string:

`"{\"action\"=>\"bla\"}`

How can I get this string value without the escape characters? I've tried deep transforming and simply gsubbing but neither of these feel like I'm doing it right..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any escape characters.

What you're looking at is the *representation* of the string when *inspected* on the console.

Consider the following:

```
irb(main):001:0> x = '"hello"'
=> "\"hello\""
irb(main):002:0> puts x
"hello"
```

The string does not contain any backslashes. But when *inspecting* it, backslashes must be present in order to distinguish "end of string" vs "quotation mark, inside the string".

Comment: Does that mean when I do calculations involving the string there will be no escape characters present?

Comment: There **aren't** any escape characters present.

Comment: Try using `puts`, to print the string to the console.

Comment: For another example, suppose you have `x = "\n"`. When *inspecting* the value, you see `\n` displayed literally. But when printing it, you see this is displayed "normally" (as a new line). Inspecting strings is a much more convenient way of being able to tell, unambiguously, exactly what the real value is.

Comment: Yup - I can see now you need some way to distinguish quote marks included in the string vs quote marks denoting the start of the string - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The least ugly way I can do this is:

```
JSON.parse(string.gsub("=>", ":").gsub(":nil,", ":null,"))
```

If anyone has a less ugly way please let me know